# How do I implement the stack::top() function?

Tags: c++, stack

my question is how do I implement the Stack::top() function without using the std::stack library? In other words, how do I write my own top() function that returns the top element of the stack without popping it for my following stack?

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class Stack
{
private:
    int *p;
    int top,length;

public:
    Stack(int = 0);
    ~Stack();

    void push(int);
    int pop();
    void display();
};

Stack::Stack(int size)
{
    top=-1;
    length=size;
    while(length <= 0)                //If the stack size is zero, allow user to mention it at runtime
    {
        cout<<"Stack of zero size"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter a size for stack : ";
        cin >> length;
    }
    p=new int[length];
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    delete [] p;
}

void Stack::push(int elem)
{
    if(top==(length-1))     //If the top reaches to the maximum stack size
    {
        throw overflow_error("Can't push onto a full stack");
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        p[top]=elem;
    }
}
int Stack::pop()
{
    if(top==-1)
    {
       throw underflow_error("Can't pop from an empty stack");
    }
    int ret=p[top];
    top--;
    length--;

    return ret;
}

void Stack::display()
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        cout<<p[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int len;

    cout<<"Enter a size for stack : ";
    cin >> len;
    Stack s1(len);
    try{
        s1.push(1);
        s1.display();
        s1.push(2);
        s1.push(3);
        s1.push(4);
        s1.push(5);
        s1.display();
        s1.pop();
        s1.display();
        s1.pop();
        s1.display();
        s1.pop();
        s1.display();
        s1.pop();
        s1.display();
        s1.pop();
        s1.display();
    }
    catch(overflow_error){
        cerr<< "Illegal operation. Cannot push onto a full stack.";
        return -1;
    }
    catch(underflow_error){
        cerr<< "Illegal operation. Cannot pop from an empty stack.";
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I think there's some bug in your code. Why do you reduce `length` in `pop()`? That way you reduce the maximum size of your stack every time you call `pop()`, which probably isn't intentional.

Comment: Nice catch, thank you, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already store `top`, you can just return `p[top]`. Or in other words: `top()` would essentially be the same as `pop()`, it just won't remove the top element.

Comment: With the added test for underflow.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Is the code like this? `int Stack::stackTop()
{
 //check if stack is empty first
 if (top == -1)
    {
        throw underflow_error("Can't pop from an empty stack");
    }
 else
 {
  cout << "First element is: " + p[top] << endl;
 }
}`

Comment: Just copy your `pop()` 1:1 and remove the line `top--;`.